# how to change colorPrimary , colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent of an app Programatically

Tags: android

Is it possible to override  `colorPrimary , colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent` values Programatically and change Accordingly from java code at Runtime ? If Possible please help.

Comment: You can not do that. Create a new `Style` overriding with new values and apply it to Activity.

Comment: You cant do that because themes are unchanging over time or unable to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. But you can create multiple Styles and change the Style used by the activity at runtime. To do that use `setTheme()` before calling `setContentView()` and `super.onCreate()` method inside `onCreate()` method of the activity!

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  setTheme(R.style.MyTheme); // (for Custom theme)

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  this.setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);
}
```